# How to get 4 characters of a string at a time iterating backwards

Tags: loops, for-loop

If I have a string, say "abcdefghij"

How can I iterate and get to characters backwards at a time.

For example

**first loop** : `ghij`

**second loop**: `fedc`

**third loop**: `ab`

Im using C++ but dont feel like its simple enough i should be able to adapt any language

Heres what I have so far:

```
for(long unsigned int i=0; i<s.length();i+=4){
    digits.push_back(std::stoi(s.substr(i, 4)));
}
```

My issue is that this is left justified, not right justified

Comment: This site is not a code-writing service. We can help you with *specific* questions about *your* code, ideally accompanied by an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: @Bohemian question has been updated to reflect this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pseudo code:

```
iterate i from s.length stepping by -4, while i > 0
    start = max(i - 4, 0)
    part = s.substring(start, i)
```